# Object-oriented design / architecture for a simple CRUD application

Tags: vb.net, class, architecture, encapsulation

I have been programming in VB6 for a few years and now I have taken up VB.Net. I have developed a couple solutions, but the solutions are not up to common design standards. I am the only developer in a financial business. My solutions work, but I don't have anyone to learn from about correct architecture.

I am developing a new application and I want it to be done right. However, I don't know what should be a class/object etc. I think I use too many global variables and nothing is encapsulated.

The application is for expense submissions. The user (the user should be a class?) can enter an expense with line items. I am using a datagridview to show/add the line items.
There will also be a history tab that shows all the expenses for the user, and a review tab so that a reviewer on the expenses can approve line items.

Data is in SQL Server several tables, one for the expense header, one for the expense lines, one for user info. Approved expenses are inserted into a third party app on the same SQL Server database for payment.

What approach would you use in designing a simple app like this? Thank you for any advice you can give me.

Comment: Unfortunately there's really no "correct" way to answer this.  At best, I can recommend a book or two on object-oriented development.  "Domain Driven Design" by Eric Evans is a good one for conceptualizing your business objects, for example.  "Design Patterns" by Erich Gamma, et al (also known as the "Gang Of Four" book) is an in-depth examination of re-usable patterns in object-oriented designs.  These are a _bit_ heavy for a beginner, but are great material.  There's a _lot_ to learn and it can't really be encapsulated within a Stack Overflow question/answer.

Comment: If you try out a few things and identify what you think might be problems with those approaches, we can definitely recommend better approaches or help fix problems.  Not just plain old code reviews, mind you.  But things like: "Here's how I've written this class, but it feels messy and difficult to maintain.  Is there a pattern that can improve the design?" or "This function is a serious performance bottleneck.  What I'm trying to achieve is ___.  Is there a more efficient way of doing it?"

Comment: Right now I'm stepping back and defining the nouns.  I have an user, a reviewer (who is a special kind of user), an expense header, and expense lines.  I'm defining properties and methods on these.  Since they have properties and methods, are these going to be objects in the application?

Comment: They might very well be, yes. The "Domain Driven Design" book will help you to identify your entities, your aggregate roots, etc. Think of an "entity" as something that has real-world uniqueness. For example, a person is an entity. There are data elements which are associated with a person (height, weight, eye color, hair color, name, age, etc.) but those don't "identify" that person. Another person with the exact same attributes is not the same person. Conversely, think of a data structure like a set of driving directions. Two identical ones are effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a lot more studying. However one thing I've found useful for quickly developing object models without worrying too much about the database aspects is the Entity Framework. Add an Entity Model to your project and read up on that.